# ELK custom date

Tags: json, logstash

I send to `Logstash` json over `TCP`. I want add field `"timestamp"` to `JSON` with date as long

```
body.put("timestamp", new Date().getTime());
```

In logstash i see this field as `Number`.
How i can map my `timestamp` to logstash `@timestamp` or set `@timestamp` manualy. I can't change Logstash configuration.

Data input example:

```
{
"@message":{
"path":"*****$1:101",
"text":"TEST ERROR 0"
},
"@timestamp":"2018-07-14T22:54:27.579+0300",
"level":"ERROR",
"@tags":["test","java",],
"type":"logs"
}
```

Data output JSON in kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "logs-2018.07.14",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "STdjmmQB0QygPx38jLkS",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2018-07-14T20:02:30.091Z",
    "@message": {
      "path": "path",
      "requestId": "423-423",
      "text": "test"
    },
    "level": "INFO",
    "@tags": [
      "test",
      "java"
    ],
    "host": "*.*.*.*",
    "type": "logs",
    "port": 56549
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-07-14T20:02:30.091Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1531598550091
  ]
}
```

P.S. i need my own `timestamp` because i send messages in thread pool and i can lose ordering.

Comment: what do you mean by `I can't change Logstash configuration` ?

Comment: You question is not clear, for clarity can you please quote some example as to what is your input, what is the desired output ?

Comment: about "I can't change Logstash configuration" - i haven`t access to elk server

Answer (score 0):

Solution is add field `@timestamp` into root json node and set date in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format
Example:

```
{
"@message":{
"path":"*****$1:101",
"text":"TEST ERROR 0"
},
"@timestamp":"2018-07-14T22:54:27.579+0300",
"level":"ERROR",
"@tags":["test","java"],
"type":"logs"
}
```